# Android NETWORK_PROVIDER locationManager

Tags: android, location

In my app I am using location services to obtain the user location coordinates to compare the distance to the objects which are obtained from my server.

So the user must have internet connection ON due to data obtained from server.

So in that case, I decided not to use GPS_PROVIDER, but only NETWORK_PROVIDER for user location, as the user needs to have internet connection, and this is quicker as GPS.

```
 isNetwork = locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
```

Till now I checked if `isNetwork` exists then do the stuff for `NETWORK_PROVIDER`, else try `GPS_PROVIDER`.

Now the question is, if the internet connection is always on, do I still need also `GPS_PROVIDER`?

I just want to get rid of the part of code for GPS, so I want to be sure, if the user has internet connection ON, the `NETWORK_PROVIDER` will always work.

To shorten the question: does `NETWORK_PROVIDER` depend from active internet connection? Does the user need to enable the device location in Settings for using just `NETWORK_PROVIDER` and not GPS?

Comment: You should always use the gps chip as it is more exact.

Comment: I know, but in my case I don't need a very exact location, as the distances are in tens of km via airline